# How to hide a portion of axes in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want a figure that looks like the following:

[image]

As you can see the portion of the plot between 4 and 6 in the x-axis is white/deleted.
How to achieve this in matplotlib?

I tried adding a rectangle with no clipping but I could still see the axis:

```
rect = plt.Rectangle((4.6,-0.2),
                 width = 1, #11.3, 
                 height = 1,
                 facecolor='red',
                 clip_on=False,
                 linewidth = 0,
                 alpha=1.0)
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is an official [docs page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html) about broken axes. Also, Ben Dichter created a [very useful library](https://github.com/bendichter/brokenaxes).

Comment: To draw a rectangle over the x axis, you also need to set the `zorder` at least 3 (2 is the default `zorder` of lines) : `rect = plt.Rectangle(...., zorder=3)`.